# Adding Icons to desktop easily?

Tags: icons

I am brand new to Linux and just installed Ubuntu. I was wondering if there was an easier way to add icons to the desktop. Right now I have to scour the applications folders for the app, then copy and paste it to the desktop. Even then, I am unable to find the .desktop file for the app that I didn't install via Ubuntu Software Store (its called [Lightburn](https://lightburnsoftware.com/)).